# Generate a case class in scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros, treehugger

How to generate case classes in scala based on information kept in 100s of java classes? Basically, I need this for writing a wrapper for a java library.

Is it even possible? I have a feeling that no. In that case what is the best alternative?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "generate", and what do you mean by "based on information..."?

Comment: There are hundreds of case classes I need to create but doing this by hand would be tedious. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally doable. Some ideas:

1. It seems you do not need to generate code every time you compile your project. You can generate it once and either check-in into source control or publish as a library.
2. Depending on whether you have access to the source code of the Java library or not you will need to use either [.java parser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) or [.class parser](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html). Reflection may or may not work for you (the main constraint is you need to have the class in the classpath of the current JVM and load it in memory to access it via reflection API).
3. For different approaches to Scala code generation with examples see [this post](http://yefremov.net/blog/scala-code-generation/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can generate them before compilation. You will want to introspect the Java classes (maybe using the reflection API) and then generate corresponding Scala source code. You can either generate it once and copy to the repository or create a generator and use it in the building tool, e.g. in SBT.

You can generate the code either by hand (by concatenating the strings) or by a library like [TreeHugger](http://eed3si9n.com/treehugger/introduction.html)

Comment: It's worth saying that you could generate at compile time with a macro, which might get closer to the build cycle you want.

Comment: Surely you can, but I am not sure about benefits. When generating by a SBT hook, it is the same build cycle and you have to learn less new API.

Comment: @lmm can you please show me a basic example how to do it?